# async function doesn't return value required

Tags: node.js, async-await, pg

I am trying to get data from a postresql database using async/await. the problem that I face is that the fetchMembers loads the data but it doesn't return that data, but only a blank object.

```
//server.js
const members = require('./memberDB')

app.get('/' , (req, res) => {
    res.json(members)
    console.log('Members: ',JSON.stringify(members))
})

//MemberDB.js

const fetchMembers =  async function() {

    const { Client, Pool } = require('pg')

    const pool = new Pool({
      user: 'user',
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'whatevs',
      password: '',
      port: 5432,
    })

    const loadData = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM members;')
    const data = await loadData.rows
    console.log('data -> ', data)//I get this data correctly

    return data // but I don't get the return value even if I remove 'await' from the 'loadData.rows'
}

module.exports.members = fetchMembers()
```

Comment: `loadData.rows` isn't a Promise, you should not be able to `await` it.  That might not be your problem, but it is certainly not a solution to add `await` there.

Comment: thanks. but it even doesn't work without that, as I made clear. do you have any idea what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make fetchMembers returns a promise and await on it in the request handler.

```
 const fetchMembers =  async function() {

    const { Client, Pool } = require('pg')

    const pool = new Pool({
      user: 'user',
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'whatevs',
      password: '',
      port: 5432,
    })

    return pool.query('SELECT * FROM members;')        
}
module.exports.members = fetchMembers;
```

in the route:

```
    app.get('/' , async (req, res) => {
       const loadData = await fetchMembers();
       const data = loadData.rows;
       res.json(data);           
   })
```

The problem was you call fetchMembers and await on the promise inside it but that do not block the code. the execution of the req handler continue and the members was not resolved yet. So you have two solution either to await in fetchMembers and the request handler or return a promise and await only in the request handler. Like Paul said it is better to export the function itself.

Comment: This will result in a members list that is cached for the duration of the process

Answer (score 1):

`MemberDB.js` exports the result of calling `fetchMembers()`, which is an `async` function and will therefore always return a `Promise`.

## Fix

```
app.get('/' , async (req, res) => {
    res.json(await members)
    console.log('Members: ',JSON.stringify(await members))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re calling the function upon requiring the file but not awaiting it.  This has two effects.  First, your members variable will be empty of data and second, since you call it upon require you’ll only get whatever members were in the database the first time the file is required due to the required cache.  The correct approach would be to export the function like so:

```
    module.exports = fetchMembers; // note no parentheses
```

Then call that correctly in your route:

```
    const fetchMembers = require(“./dbMembers”);

     app.get(‘/‘, async (req, res) => {
            const members = await fetchMembers();
            res.send(members); // obviously add erro catching and stuff 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function in a try catch statement so you don't get silent error, example:

```
const fetchMembers =  async () => {
    try
    {
       const { Pool } = require('pg')

       const pool = new Pool({
         user: 'user',
         host: 'localhost',
         database: 'whatevs',
         password: '',
         port: 5432,
       })

       return await pool.query('SELECT * FROM members;')
    }
    catch(reason){
        console.log(reason)
    }
}

console.log(fetchMembers())
```

Comment: await doesn't work before calling the fetchMemebers(), coz its not returning another promise. thank for the try, catch though